# Use HAVING or WHERE?

Tags: sql, sql-server, inner-join, where-clause, having-clause

I am confused about when to use HAVING and when to use WHERE. I need to

> Find all of the bugs on software Debugger that pertain to the /main.html

This is my query

```
select Tickets.TicketID, b.Data
from Bugs b
Inner Join Tickets
On b.TicketID = Tickets.TicketID
Inner Join Softwares
on Software.SoftwareId = Tickets.SoftwareID
where Software.URL = 'http://debugger.com' and Tickets.Title = '/main.html'
```

NOTE: THIS GIVES ME DESIRED RESULT
But I want to make sure I am not missing anything important here. Maybe should I use HAVING somewhere here?

Also in order to make the query perform better on a large dataset, I have created an index on foreign keys

```
create nonclustered index IX_Tickets_SoftwareId
on [dbo].[Tickets] ([SoftwareId])
go
create nonclustered index IX_Bugs_TicketsId
on [dbo].[Bugs] ([TicketsId])
```

Am doing allright?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your query is fine. You want to filter individual records, which is what the `WHERE` clause does.

The `HAVING` clause comes into play in aggregate queries - queries that use `GROUP BY`, and its purpose is to filter *groups of records*, using aggregate functions (such as `SUM()`, `MAX()` or the-like). It makes no sense for your query, that does not use aggregation.

Incidently, I note that your are not returning anything from the `softwares` table, so that join is used for filtering only. In such situation, I find that `exists` is more appropriate, because it is explicit about its purpose:

```
select t.ticketid, b.data
from bugs b
inner join tickets t on b.ticketid = t.ticketid
where t.title = '/main.html' and exists (
    select 1 
    from softwares s
    where s.softwareid = t.softwareid and s.url = 'http://debugger.com'
)
```

For performance, consider an index on `softwares(softwareid, url)`, so the subquery execute efficiently. An index on `tickets(ticketid, title)` might also help.

Comment: Thank you very much.

Comment: quick question, Am I doing okay with creating indexing on foreign keys? The goal is to make the query perform better on large datasets. Let's say I have  500 million unique bugs across 200.000 of softwares? Is using "Indexing" a good solution here?

Comment: Okay, so do i need to add them using Include (url)  and include (title) correct?

Answer (score 2):

**WHERE** is used to filter records before any groupings take place. **HAVING** is used to filter values after they have been groups. Only columns or expressions in the group can be included in the HAVING clause's